# how to remove docker with yum or any other approach

Tags: rhel, yum, docker, rpm, container

today we installed docker with the following rpm's ( *32 rpm's* ) , on `rhel 7.2`

```
rpm -qa --last|more
libselinux-devel-2.5-15.el7.x86_64            Sun 10 May 2020 07:03:31 AM UTC
libselinux-2.5-15.el7.i686                    Sun 10 May 2020 07:03:31 AM UTC
docker-ce-19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64                Sun 10 May 2020 07:03:31 AM UTC
libsepol-2.5-10.el7.i686                      Sun 10 May 2020 07:03:27 AM UTC
docker-ce-cli-19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64            Sun 10 May 2020 07:03:26 AM UTC
libsepol-devel-2.5-10.el7.x86_64              Sun 10 May 2020 07:03:19 AM UTC
libseccomp-2.3.1-4.el7.x86_64                 Sun 10 May 2020 07:03:19 AM UTC
containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64           Sun 10 May 2020 07:03:19 AM UTC
setools-libs-3.3.8-4.el7.x86_64               Sun 10 May 2020 07:03:06 AM UTC
policycoreutils-python-2.5-34.el7.x86_64      Sun 10 May 2020 07:03:06 AM UTC
libsemanage-python-2.5-14.el7.x86_64          Sun 10 May 2020 07:03:06 AM UTC
libselinux-python-2.5-15.el7.x86_64           Sun 10 May 2020 07:03:06 AM UTC
container-selinux-2.119.1-1.c57a6f9.el7.noarch Sun 10 May 2020 07:03:06 AM UTC
.
.
.
.
.
```

now we want to remove the docker

what is the best way to remove the docker rpm's as described above

the first way is like this

```
yum remove libselinux-devel-2.5-15.el7.x86_64 libselinux-2.5-15.el7.i686 docker-ce-19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64 ....
```

but in fact removing the rpm's by `yum remove` with all list is **clumsy**

any other ideas ?

Comment: Consider using `yum history list` and then `yum history undo <n>` ?

Comment: Record for future readers: on RHEL8+ you can just `dnf remove docker-ce` and all remaining packages will be removed as unused dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply undo the last transaction:

```
yum history undo last
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this -

`rpm -qa | grep docker | xargs yum remove -y`

OR

`rpm -qa --last | awk '{system("yum remove -y "$1)}'`